# SQL Error [2201B]: ERROR: invalid regular expression: invalid character range

Tags: regex, postgresql

```
select * from app_user au where au.email !~ '^[a-zA-Z0-9_!#$%&\u2019*+/=?`{|}~^.-]+@[A-Za-z0-9-]+(?:\.[A-Za-z-0-9-]+)*$'
```

I  have following select with regex, it gives me error:

> SQL Error [2201B]: ERROR: invalid regular expression: invalid
> character range

Do You know what's wrong with this regex?
I tried it with https://www.regextester.com/ and it's working for me

Comment: `[A-Za-z-0-9-]` - see the `-` between `z` and `0`?

Comment: yes, as Wiktor said, the problem is that extra dash between `z` and `0` in the last character class